# How to get selected day/month and year from vb datepicker

Tags: vb6

in a datepicker i use DateValue(Now) to get the current date . it gives date-month-year

but i require to store only the month value from the same datepicker. wht shoud i do ?

Answer (score 3):

The month can be extracted from the date using the Format$ function:

```
Print "Month is ";Format$(yourDateValue,"mm")
```

See [this page](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/formating-dates-and-times-vb6) for all the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

- To get the month as a string use Format as Richard suggests
   `MsgBox "Month name is " & Format$(yourDateValue, "mmm")`
- To get the month number use [DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262714%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)
   `MsgBox "Month number is " & DatePart("m", yourDateValue)`